# How to Import sass file to single components in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, saas

I think it might be silly question to ask but trust me I am in trouble and frustrated . Actually I have two components one is `Home` and second is `Dashboard` . I created two sass file for individuals components mean one for `home` and second is for `dashboard`. For Home it working fine but when I include sass file into dashbaord component then it break `home page` component style . How to fix this issue . I want to implement it separately, it should be independent.

I also used react-router so please help me to achieve my goal

Comment: how are you importing it?

Comment: `import "./dashboardStyle.scss";`

Comment: how are you importing your sass file in home component?

Comment: @CecilJohnTantay I created fiddle, please have a look ( code )

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/chtkus42/1/

Comment: @CecilJohnTantay could you please check

Comment: all I see is an App component that is importing `./App.css`. That should be scss. can you do it on codesandbox instead?

Comment: @CecilJohnTantay `./App.css` file have style and it does not applied on dashboard component

Comment: When I remove dashboard style then everything back normal

Comment: Can you post a snippet of your Dashboard component and your Home component? Edit your original post

Answer (score 2):

You can implement independent sass file to react component by using Sass css modules.

You have to create two sass files Home.module.scss and Dashboard.module.scss

```
.btn {
  color:red;
}
```

You can import like this .

```
import {btn} from "./Home.module.scss";
import {btn} from "./Dashboard.module.scss";
```

where btn is the class name you have in sass files.

Then you can use that class in component like this .

```
<a className={btn}> Button </a>
```

This way you can use sass file independently .
Let me know if need more explanation .

Comment: How to import all classes from Sass file ?

Comment: You can do like this import  {class1, class2, class3}  from "./Home.module.scss";

Comment: Or you can use destructuring .

Comment: if I have thousand class in file then I will do like this ?

Comment: No, you can use destructuring .

Comment: import styles from  "./Home.module.scss"; Then use like this. <a className={styles.btn}> Button </a>

Comment: can  you do it please ?

Comment: import styles from  "./Home.module.scss"; Then use like this. <a className={styles.btn}> Button </a>. is that help?

Comment: not working . not with {btn} and not with descructing

Comment: You can check this . https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-hawking-i44zb

Comment: I am importing background image which was define in .scss file as class but it not working

Comment: This seems like a huge PITA and very inefficient. We're going backwards in development practices now. React's next greatest thing will be using tables for everything.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you installed sass by installing `node-sass`.

All you need to do is to import them into a component that needs sass at the top of the js file.

`import './dashboard.scss'`